# How do I align ReSharpers "cleanup code" with Visual Studio's "format document"

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I'm a big fan of ReSharpers "cleanup code" feature. Especially the Solution wide clean up.

But I use Visual Studio's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Format document), it formats the code slightly differed than ReSharper.

I'm on a quest to align ReSharper with Visual Studio (not the other way... because you can not share Visual Studio settings in the solution/source control system).

So I'm after something like this:

```
<Configuration>
  <CodeStyleSettings>
    <Sharing>SOLUTION</Sharing>
    <CSharp>
      <FormatSettings>
        <SPACE_AROUND_MULTIPLICATIVE_OP>True</SPACE_AROUND_MULTIPLICATIVE_OP>
        <SPACE_BEFORE_TYPEOF_PARENTHESES>False</SPACE_BEFORE_TYPEOF_PARENTHESES>
      </FormatSettings>
    </CSharp>
  </CodeStyleSettings>
</Configuration>
```

Which other settings will help ReSharper format code like Visual Studio?

Comment: You can export VS settings and put them in source control. We do this.

Comment: But it's still a Visual Studio setting, and you have to remember to check them in and out the right place. And you don't have live templates. And you only have limited settings. And you can't have different settings across solutions. And you can't run code cleanup on an entire solution. And, And, And... you get the point ;-) With ReSharper the settings are part of the solution, and are automatically deployed, and you have so many settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution we use is to remap Visual Studio's shortcut for "Format Document <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>" to ReSharper's Code Cleanup. We also use a plugin to manage sharing ReSharper settings through source control. The built in ReSharper shared settings functionality does not share all settings e.g. Inspection Severities and custom Code Cleanup profiles.

I have a [blog article](http://gojisoft.com/blog/2010/05/10/coding-standards-using-resharper/) that describes sorting the keyboard mapping out, and setting up the "manage settings" plugin:

Comment: URL is dead, domain can be bought.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I've mapped Visual Studio's shortcut for "Format Document Ctrl K, D" to Resharper's Code Cleanup:

[image]